# Being as instead of "beensya"

Tags: meaning

I often hear people using the term "beensya".  I am assuming they mean "being as".  How is the term "being as" correctly used in English.

Comment: Where are these people who say this? It certainly doesn't sound like "being as" is pronounced by anybody I've spoken to. (And most people I speak to don't use "being as" in speech.) I would assume "beensya" is short for something else.

Comment: "What beensya here, maan" is "What brings you here, man?" in some kind of slang.

Comment: Please do add context. Since you say that this is not a one-off but something you hear often, certainly you can easily produce an example or five.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: In this specific case I think OP would find it extremely difficult to provide *links* to instances of his specific written form (I doubt I've ever seen it before). But he *has* said what he supposes people mean by it, and the usage is perfectly familiar to me (if not to all Anglophones, judging by various comments). There's only really one context where *being as* is commonly used (i.e. - where it means ***since***), so I don't see that "more context" is particularly necessary here in order to understand and answer the question (to what extent is the usage "correct"?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers all true, except I am not asking for *links*, and I am not asking for the context in which "being as" used (I can produce any number of examples myself), I am asking for the context in which "beensya" is used. And the point, of course, is to verify whether OP's assumption that "beensya" has anything to do with "being as" is at all correct.

Comment: Wait! Are you asking about 'beensya' at all? Or, are you asking *How is the term "being as" correctly used in English?* -- Only one question per post.

Comment: @Kris: this isn't two questions. Would you suggest breaking up the question containing: *How do you pronounce* ***going to***?  and *What does **gonna** mean*?

Comment: @PeterShor *How is the term "being as" correctly used in English?* is nothing about *beensya*, which everyone is discussing about instead. See two?

Answer (score 2):

Although OP's **beensya** isn''t familiar to me as a written contraction, I personally use and hear **being as** quite often in casual speech (with the meaning *since, it being the case that*).

[Here's a typical example](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_T5MAZR9NYAC&pg=PT1260&dq=%22being%20as%20you%20want%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dttnUpPyIaK30QWt04GYBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22being%20as%20you%20want%22&f=false) from Google Books. But it's worth noting that there are only 9 instances of the specific text  *"**being** as you want"*, whereas there are a claimed 12,600 instances of the (to me, equivalent) version [*"**seeing** as you want"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22being%20as%20you%20want%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#psj=1&q=%22seeing%20as%20you%20want%22&tbm=bks).

It's a bit more awkward to come up with an "expanded" replacement for the more common version explicitly including the verb **to see**. The best I can do is say **seensya** = ***since I/we can see that...***

Without question, I'd say both forms are casual/informal. Purely my own opinion, but I suspect they might be more common in BrE than AmE.

---

It may be worth noting that in rapid speech, ***seeing as you*** and ***since you*** may be effectively indistinguishable, so it's possible some [all?!] usages arise from mishearings.

Comment: You mean "beensya" is short for "being as *you*", not just "being as". That makes sense, although for American English, "being as you" seems too formal to me to be used much in speech.

Comment: @Peter: Interesting that you think the construction is "formal". It feels extremely *informal* to me. But as I write, it's just occured to me there's also the possibility of mis-hearing ***since you*** as ***seein' as you*** (and vice-versa). I think that may also have some relevance to the usage, so I'll edit it in.

Comment: I'm with Peter - if I know anyone who'd use "being as", they'd pronounce it properly.  The more informal speakers would use "since" instead, IMO.

Comment: @Kristina, Peter: All I can say is that Google Books claims 2,770 results for [*but seeing as **it's***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+seeing+as+it's%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is obviously an "informal" context, when compared with just 630 instances of [*but seeing as **it is***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+seeing+as+it+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Which accords with my own intuition that the usage is primarily, if not exclusively, informal.